# How to clear view definition cache infor M3 smartoffice

Tags: arp

I am using Infor M3
http://www.infor.com/product_summary/erp/m3/

Is there a way to clear view definition cache from Smartoffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After bit of research i found this on smartofficeblog on a comment

The url is:http://smartofficeblog.com/2011/12/01/personalizations-in-m3/

mforms://_command?value=clear lngcache  //this will clear lang cache

mforms://_command?value=clear view all  //this will clear all view def cache

mforms://_command?value=clear view MNS150 //this will clear MNS150 screen view cache

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following commands:-

Clear all view definitions : mforms://_command?value=clear view all

(OR)

clear view definition of program MNS150: mforms://_command?value=clear view MNS150

Answer (score 1):

The command behind the clear button is:

mforms://_command/?value=clear custcache

More information at https://m3ideas.org/2016/06/09/clear-global-customization-cache/